# Custom hand cursor in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, basic

I am working on a my app and I managed to change the normal mouse cursor very easy using this code:

```
Dim cur As Icon
cur = (My.Resources.NewCursor)
Me.Cursor = New Cursor(cur.Handle)`
```

Now I'd like to change the default "Hand" Cursor to a new one but I can't manage to do it, it won't let me `New Cursors.Hand` or `Me.Cursors.Hand`, also on the internet I find only complicated methods and I know there is an easy one, I just can't find it.

Comment: If you want a custom cursor then you'll first have to create it.  Project > Add New Item > General > Cursor File.  Let your creative juices flow.  Albeit that you tend to find out that there's not that much wrong with Cursors.Hand (without New or Me).  So just use Me.Cursor = Cursors.Hand

Comment: Thank you. I was looking exactly for this.